# ./configure error while installing conky

Tags: linux

I've downloaded conky from GitHub and when I try to use the ./configure command, I get this following error :

```
   bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I opened my terminal in the Src folder and tried this command. What am I missing?

[This is the screenshot of the terminal and the downloaded conky folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PleZj.png)

Comment: Move to the folder that contains configure?

Answer (score 0):

I see CMakeLists.txt and doubled checked, per the [documentation](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Installation) use [cmake](https://cmake.org/)

> #### 1.10 and later versions
>
> Conky 2 will use cmake instead of autotools which means you won't need autoconf and automake anymore but you'll need cmake.

autoconf and automake (and autogen) are what generally drive "configure".

> You will need the tolua library (Ref.), which can be installed for Linux with `apt-get install libtolua-dev libtolua++5.1-dev`. You also need the following development packages if you keep the default cmake configuration: `apt-get install libx11-dev libxft-dev libxdamage-dev libncurses5-dev libxinerama-dev`.
>
> Then, building conky will work like this:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir build
> $ cd build
> $ ccmake ..
> # this will launch a curses-based UI where you can configure
> # everything, when you are ready you can build as usual:
> $ make  # This will compile conky in the `src` subdirectory
> $ make install
> ```